# "Figure A and B" or "Figures A and B"

Tags: grammar, british-english

My question is: which one is correct to talk about two figures in my writing?

1. "Figure A and B are ..."
2. "Figures A and B are ..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Number two is correct. The predicate is "are," which is the predicate for a plural subject. The subject is "figures," which is plural. A and B modify the subject but don't affect its plurality.

Comment: Coordinated items become plural.  You wouldn't say "the cat and the dog is ..."

Answer (score 3):

"A" And "B" are names of your figures, and so the phrase "A and B" is a compound appositive. See e.g. http://www.qcsd.org/cms/lib04/PA01000005/Centricity/Domain/229/appositives.doc

There are two different figures, so it seems logical to say "Figures A and B..."

Answer (score 1):

It would be correct to say "Figures A and B are...". An alternative would be to say "Figure A and Figure B are..."

Comment: Why the vote to delete?